# How to select a specific string in a certain patern in xpath

Tags: regex, xpath, scrapy

i want to select a string between `</span>` and `<br/>` for instance below

```
<span class="pl">制片国家/地区:</span>
中国大陆
<br/>
```

Of course i transfer all these chinese words into Unicode Format
 here i'd like to select "中国大陆" from this html file.
 i tried it with xpath and regex in this way:

```
sel.xpath("*").re(r'制片国家/地区:</span>\s*(.*)<br/>')
```

it should be "中国大陆",but i get a empty string.what should i do

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to select your text:

```
//span[@class="pl"]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

- `//span[@class="pl"]` - Find a span with class `pl` (exactly) at any level of the document...
- `/following-sibling::text()[1]` - ... and take the next text node following it.